# looking for samples to validate UTF-8

Tags: c#, validation, utf-8

Suppose I have a byte stream (array), and I want to write code (using .Net C#) to validate whether it is valid UTF-8 byte sequence or not. I want to write code from scratch because I need to report the exact location where there is invalid byte sequences and may even remove invalid bytes -- not just want to get yes or no about whether the byte stream/array is valid.

Are there any sample codes to make reference? If no C# code, simple samples in C++/Java are also appreciated. Thanks!

For the invalid byte sequences of UTF-8, I mean

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3):

What you need is [DecoderFallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderfallback.aspx). When the `Encoding` class is trying to convert a sequence of bytes to the target encoding, you can specify fallback behaviour:

- Either [report error and stop processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderexceptionfallback(VS.80).aspx).
- Or [find the error and replace it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderreplacementfallback(VS.80).aspx).

Using `UTF8Encoding` and `DecoderReplacementFallback` you can achieve just what you're looking for.

Comment: @DreamSonic, when using the following code snippet to load XML docuemnt and check against whether it is UTF-8 encoded using your suggested solution above, how to add fallback functions?

                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.Load("c:\\abc.xml");

Comment: In this case you should use the XmlDocument.LoadXml(...) method instead of the Load(...). You should open the stream, read all its bytes and try to convert them to a given encoding using Encoding.GetString(...).

Comment: Otherwise the framework will use its default behaviour: that is, open the file (assuming it's UTF8), read the `<?xml encoding` directive and maybe change the encoding, then convert the contents of the file to the given encoding ignoring all the errors.

Answer (score 3):

```
static void CheckUTF8(byte[] data)
{
    new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetCharCount(data);
}
```

Throws a `DecoderFallbackException` on invalid data. `DecoderFallbackException.Index` should point to the index of the invalid sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the original question asked for, even if it isn't quite what the original poster really needed.  However, I've gone and written [some C code to validate a byte stream as utf-8](http://snowplow.org/martin/utf8checker/), and made it available freely.  Maybe someone else directed at this question via a Google search will find it useful.

It takes one byte at a time, so is suitable for stream processing, and classifies everything into either valid UTF-8 or one of these possible errors in the byte sequence:

```
/* Ways a UTF stream can screw up */
/* a multibyte sequence without as many continuation bytes as expected.  e.g. [ef 81] 48 */
#define MISSING_CONTINUATION 1 
/* A continuation byte when not expected */
#define UNEXPECTED_CONTINUATION 2 
/* A full multibyte sequence encoding something that should have been encoded shorter */
#define OVERLONG_FORM 3
/* A full multibyte sequence encoding something larger than 10FFFF */
#define OUT_OF_RANGE 4
/* A full multibyte sequence encoding something in the range U+D800..U+DFFF */
#define BAD_SCALAR_VALUE 5
/* bytes 0xFE or 0xFF */
#define INVALID 6
```

This validator has the nice property that if *a* and *b* are valid utf-8 byte streams, and *x* is some other stream of bytes, then the concatenation *a* + *x* + *b* will be decoded as all of the characters encoded in *a*, some combination of characters and errors, then all of the characters encoded in *x*.  That is, an invalid sequence of bytes can't eat validly encoded characters that start after the bad bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Nice point. I didn't know that there exists non valid UTF-8 sequences.

The article at the wikiedia is a starting point but I don't think that you can have a complete test. Can you? I am interested

A complete test means that for every sequence you can have a function that answers yes or no for every possible sequence. A full function.

The point is what to do or to return if your sequence is not complete (a short sequence). As far as I know there are some editors that add a special character in order to fulfill it. May be you should handle such cases as invalid sequences and then your test will be complete. 
I wonder if this is the only case.

Anyway, I will put this question as a favourite in order to keep track of answers. Sure somebody will illuminate us.

Comment: Confused. What do you mean test? :-)

Actually I am a developed, I need simple samples which implement the same function to make reference. Appreciated if you could give me some reference samples. I have some invalid UTF-8 encoded samples to make test at hand.